# Error while creating a react app in my pc

Tags: reactjs

there are some folders in my pc where I'm not able to create react apps using npx create-react-app.

[image]

this error comes in some directories only.

I've tried installing npx create-react-app globally too. I get this error.

Comment: Let me guess. You can create apps on drive C but not D?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me more like a file permission issue in this folder rather than a problem related to create-react-app. The process fails at creating the app folder (mkdir).

As a first step, I'd check if it's possible to create a folder manually in there by navigating into the folder in Windows Explorer, entering "cmd" in the navigation bar and trying to create a folder at this place (command: "mkdir test").

If this also fails, you should check the folder permissions (right click on the folder, Properties, Security). Your user account should be added to the permissions list with full permissions or at least write/change permissions.